# How do I do the required route(s) for getting internet traffic to/from my client assigned public IPv4s on my L2TP server

Tags: networking, network-interface, route, l2tp

I have a server running Ubuntu Server 20.04 which has two ethernet interfaces and is hosting the L2TP server (using accel-ppp).

'eno1' has a single public IPv4 address assigned.

'eno2' has access to a /26 public IPv4 block which I'd like to make use of from another location via an L2TP server. Details further down.

Now what I'm trying to do is make it so my router, at another location, can connect to the L2TP server and have a public facing IPv4 as well as a /27 public IPv4 routed to it from splitting the /26 public IPv4 mentioned earlier. For example, x.x.161.64/27.

While I can ping the IP of the router connected to the L2TP server, from the L2TP server, as well as any /27 IPv4 I assigned via the router's LAN, I can't figure out how to get a route to the internet or beyond presumably the L2TP server's own gateway IP (x.x.161.122).

eno1

```
IP address:  x.x.176.62 (public IPv4)
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway IP:  x.x.176.254
```

eno2

```
IP address:  x.x.161.125 (public IPv4)
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.252 (split from what is actually a /26)
Gateway IP:  x.x.161.126
```

My router assigned IP addresses, that's connecting to the L2TP server but aren't currently able to access the internet or go beyond x.x.161.122 (the L2TP server's gateway IP address - I believe) it seems.

```
x.x.161.121/30
x.x.161.64/27
```

On this Ubuntu server I have accel-ppp installed and configured as an L2TP server. In `/etc/accel-ppp.conf` I have the following:

```
[modules]
log_file

pptp
l2tp

auth_mschap_v2
auth_mschap_v1
auth_pap

chap-secrets

ippool

pppd_compat

[core]
log-error=/var/log/accel-ppp/core.log
thread-count=4

[common]
single-session=replace

[ppp]
verbose=1
min-mtu=1280
mtu=1400
mru=1400
ipv4=require
ipv6=deny
ipv6-intf-id=0:0:0:1
ipv6-peer-intf-id=0:0:0:2
ipv6-accept-peer-intf-id=1
lcp-echo-interval=1
lcp-echo-failure=5
lcp-echo-timeout=120
unit-cache=1

[pptp]
verbose=1
#echo-interval=30
#ip-pool=pptp
#ipv6-pool=pptp
#ipv6-pool-delegate=pptp
ifname=pptp%d

[l2tp]
verbose=1
ifname=l2tp%d

[dns]
dns1=8.8.8.8
dns2=8.8.4.4

[client-ip-range]
disable

[ip-pool]
gw-ip-address=x.x.161.122
attr=Framed-Pool
x.x.161.121/30

[log]
log-file=/var/log/accel-ppp/accel-ppp.log
log-emerg=/var/log/accel-ppp/emerg.log
log-fail-file=/var/log/accel-ppp/auth-fail.log
copy=1
level=3

[pppd-compat]
verbose=1

[chap-secrets]
chap-secrets=/etc/ppp/chap-secrets
```

Current ip route:

```
default via x.x.161.126 dev eno2 proto static
default via x.x.176.254 dev eno1 proto dhcp src x.x.176.62 metric 100
x.x.176.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src x.x.176.62
x.x.176.254 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src x.x.176.62 metric 100
x.x.161.64/27 via x.x.161.121 dev l2tp0
x.x.161.121 dev l2tp0 proto kernel scope link src x.x.161.122
x.x.161.124/30 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src x.x.161.125
```

Current route:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         x.x.161.126     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno2
default         x.x.176.254     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
x.x.176.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
x.x.176.254     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eno1
x.x.161.64      x.x.161.121     255.255.255.224 UG    0      0        0 l2tp0
x.x.161.121     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 l2tp0
x.x.161.124     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 eno2
```

Current ifconfig:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet x.x.176.62  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast x.x.176.255
        inet6 x:x:x:x::  prefixlen 56  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::d250:99ff:feda:91b6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d0:50:99:da:91:b6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet x.x.161.125  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast x.x.161.127
        inet6 fe80::d250:99ff:feda:91b5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d0:50:99:da:91:b5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

l2tp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
        inet 198.244.161.122  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination x.x.161.121
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
```

How would I go about making it so, for example, the router IP address x.x.161.121 would be able to reach the internet and be reachable from the internet? Presumably it would need to somehow have a route to x.x.161.126, the gateway IP address of the entire original /26 IPv4 block.

If there's a simpler or different approach I should be taking please say. I don't want to do NAT as that I imagine defeats what I'm trying to do.

Hopefully I've been reasonably clear and provided plenty of details, if there's more details you need please ask. I've been trying to get my head round this for nearly two days. Playing around with changing routes is a little new to me. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

EDIT: It doesn't look hopeful that I'll get an answer here so I might just have to see about finding an expert to hire for this task, assuming quotes aren't ridiculously pricey. If someone does read this question and knows the answer then I'd be really grateful to hear your solution! Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider posting the question over at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I didn't consider that. However, I've just finished and managed to figure it out in a largely roundabout way, but it works. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further experimentation, I think I've started to grasp the importance and usefulness of policy based routing, although a bit late. The good news is that I've now got what I want fully working but in a sort of roundabout way.

I'm using CentOS with SoftEther VPN Server (L2TP). With this I currently have 32 connections/logins setup, on the Firebrick they each have their own routing table. Each of them also have a unique public IPv4 address. SoftEther has been the only way I've managed to successfully get an internet connection without NAT, I believe because it makes a virtual network interface (hidden to the O/S) which bridges the L2TP connections and the ethernet interface (e.g. eth1/eno2) on an ethernet level.

With this, I've instructed the Firebrick's firewall (my router) through dozens of rules to jump between the various routing tables for each L2TP connection and the routing table that the port for my LAN has, and vice versa. The LAN interface still uses my public IPv4 /26 but realistically it's not directly connected to the IP addresses allocated to my L2TP server connections. The first IP of that public IPv4 /26 block isn't really public facing, it's only used as a gateway IP for my LAN port and that IP isn't reachable from the internet. This works, although as I say it's a roundabout way of doing it. I still have spare IP addresses too, so can add more logins later on.

It's not exactly the best solution by any means, it's a bit ugly, but it seems to work.